# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException but library exists

Tags: java

I have created a class JDBC that work very well. But when I am trying to use that Class in another class (Authentification) I have the follow error : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet("/AuthServlet")
public class AuthServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        /*
         * The visitor has filled in the index.jsp form which contains the username and
         * the password Let's retrieve those data
         */
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("Class AuthServlet :\t Username : " + username + " | Password :" + password);

        // checking the data from the form
        Authentification auth = new Authentification(username, password);
        if (auth.isAccessGranted()) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

I don't see why the JAR is not seen on my servlet.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you importing the driver?

Comment: I imported the driver to fix the problem but it still doesn't work. I thought that the class would be find.

Comment: I thing I need to update the class path but I don't know how to do it

Comment: How are you running the servlet?

Comment: I run a JSP file first with eclipse "Run as<Run as server", I fill in the form (username and password). The servlet  is supposing to check if the user exists but the driver is not found in this class. I have create a main function in my JDBC Class for debugging and the connection is a success.

Comment: I have finally resolved my problem by going to Properties<Deployment assembly<Add<Archive from file system< I select my jar file
Thanks for your help :)